# ODBCAD.exe same datasource in system32 and syswow64

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-server-2008-r2, odbc, dsn

Currently i want to proof, which odbc data sources are configurated on a windows server 2008 R2 machine. When i open `system32/odbcad32.exe` and `SysWow64/odbcad32.exe`, they contains the same sources (64-Bit OS). How to check, which architecture which DSN use? For example in windows 10, this is displayed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Here's the Microsoft answer to your question I believe --> [KB942976](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976). I've never noticed this myselft as the x86 and x64 ODBC `System DSNs` in my case are always in the applicable `system32/odbcad32.exe` for 32-bit and `SysWow64/odbcad32.exe` for the 64-bit. If you are using only `User DNS` then this seems to be the MS workaround on Server 2008 R2. You could change all to System DSNs I suppose. For Windows 8 and Server 2012, there's the PowerShell `Get-OdbcDsn` but not applicable to 2008 R2. If this helps, let me know and I'll add as an answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I also figured some thing out. You can look into the registry, where you have a section for 32bit and 64bit, which has a node for `ODBC.INI`. 32Bit: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC/ODBC.INI` and for 64BIT: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBC.INI`

Comment: @TheFurryITSnuggleBuddy Thank you for answering this question. Could you please add your comment as an answer so as to benefit the whole community and possibly elaborate a bit? That would be great.

Answer (score 2):

### Correlated Registry Paths

- **32 Bit:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/ODBC/ODBC.INI`
- **64 Bit:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ODBC/ODBC.INI`

---

The below **Microsoft** [KB942976](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976) may have the answer to your question.

I've never noticed this myself as the **x86** and **x64** ODBC System DSNs in my case are always in the applicable `system32/odbcad32.exe` for **32-bit** and `SysWow64/odbcad32.exe` for the **64-bit**.

If you are using only User DSN then this seems to be the **Microsoft** workaround on **Server 2008 R2**. You could change all to System DSNs I suppose.

For **Windows 8** and **Server 201**2, there's the **PowerShell** [Get-OdbcDsn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771015(v=wps.620).aspx) but not applicable to **Server 2008 R2**.

> ### [ODBC Administrator tool displays both the 32-bit and the 64-bit user DSNs in a 64-bit version of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942976/odbc-administrator-tool-displays-both-the-32-bit-and-the-64-bit-user-d)
>
> **Symptoms**
>
> A 64-bit version of the Microsoft Windows operating system includes
>   the following versions of the Microsoft Open Database Connectivity
>   (ODBC) Data Source Administrator tool (`Odbcad32.exe`):
>
> - The 32-bit version of the `Odbcad32.exe` file is located in the `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64` folder.
> - The 64-bit version of the `Odbcad32.exe` file is located in the `%systemdrive%\Windows\System32` folder.
>
> The `Odbcad32.exe` file displays the following types of data source
>   names (DSNs):
>
> - System DSNs
> - User DSNs
>
> **Symptom 1**
>
> The 32-bit version of the ODBC Administrator tool displays 32-bit
>   system DSNs, 32-bit user DSNs, and 64-bit user DSNs. The 64-bit
>   version of the ODBC Administrator tool displays 64-bit system DSNs,
>   32-bit user DSNs, and 64-bit user DSNs.
>
> **Symptom 2**
>
> The **SQLDataSources** function returns all versions of user DSNs,
>   regardless of the architecture of the application. The
>   **SQLDataSources** function that is called in a 32-bit application returns only system DSNs for 32-bit drivers but returns user DSNs for
>   both 32-bit drivers and 64-bit drivers. Similarly, the
>   **SQLDataSources** function that is called in a 64-bit application returns only system DSNs for 64-bit drivers but returns user DSNs for
>   both 32-bit drivers and 64-bit drivers. Therefore, if the application
>   makes a connection by using a user DSN that is returned from the
>   **SQLDataSources** function, you may receive the following error message:
>
> > Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> For example, consider the following scenario. You create a user DSN
>   for the 32-bit driver "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)." This driver
>   does not have a corresponding 64-bit version. The **SQLDataSources**
>   function that is called in a 64-bit application returns this 32-bit
>   user DSN. However, if you make a connection through this 32-bit user
>   DSN, you receive the error message that is mentioned earlier in this
>   section
>
> ---
>
> **Cause**
>
> The user DSNs are stored under the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI
> ```
>
> Registry redirection is not enabled for this registry subkey.
>   Therefore, user DSNs are visible in both the 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions of the ODBC Administrator tool.
>
> ---
>
> **Resolution**
>
> To maintain backward compatibility, no resolution for this problem is
>   currently available.
>
> ---
>
> **Workaround**
>
> To work around this problem, use the appropriate version of the ODBC
>   Administrator tool. If you build and then run an application as a
>   32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system, you must create the
>   ODBC data source by using the ODBC Administrator tool in
>   %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe. To indicate the type of DSN, you can
>   add "_32" to the 32-bit user DSNs and "_64" to the 64-bit user DSNs.
>
> ---
>
> **More Information**
>
> The 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool can be invoked from Control Panel
>   to manage user DSNs and system DSNs that are used by 64-bit processes.
>   On a 64-bit operating system, the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool is
>   used for Windows on Windows 64 (WOW64) processes. You must directly
>   invoke the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool from the SysWoW64 folder.
>   You can use the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool to manage user DSNs and
>   system DSNs that are used by WOW64 processes.
>
> **System DSNs** are stored in the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI
> ```
>
> Registry redirection is enabled for this registry subkey. Therefore,
>   system DSNs for 32-bit drivers and for 64-bit drivers are separated.
>   The 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool does not display system DSNs that
>   are created by the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool. Similarly, the
>   32-bit ODBC Administrator tool does not display system DSNs that are
>   created by the 64-bit ODBC Administrator tool. Also, the 64-bit ODBC
>   Administrator tool does not display system DSNs that use 32-bit
>   drivers. Similarly, the 32-bit ODBC Administrator tool does not
>   display system DSNs that use 64-bit drivers.
>
> **User DSNs** are stored in the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI
> ```
>
> Registry redirection is not enabled for this registry subkey.
>   Therefore, both ODBC Administrator tools display all user DSNs.
>
> For more information about registry redirection, visit the following
>   Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN) Web site:
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx

---

### Further Resources

- [ODBC Administrator tool displays both the 32-bit and the 64-bit user DSNs in a 64-bit version of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942976/odbc-administrator-tool-displays-both-the-32-bit-and-the-64-bit-user-d)