# Link to Skyward Database to MS SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to connect Skyward Database( Progress Database ) to MS SQL Server. What am I doing to connect? 
First Setup an ODBC connection to the Progress database in the ODBC Administrator in the System DSN. ( In System DSN, I am selecting ODBC driver for SQL server ). During setup, I am entering IP address on the server name. After that, I test my connection, it gives an error: Connection was not establishing. 
I don't know why is not connecting I am entering hostname correctly.

[image: Click on Add button on system DSN tab]

[image: Driver selected]

After that click on configured driver

[image: COnfiguration]

[image]

[image: Connection created]

After that, if I test this connection. its failed.

if i select other drivers datadirect SQL server

[image]

after that, i clicked on test connect it shows error that verify hostname and port

Please help me to connect skyward database and one more thing skyward is hosted on another server which is cloud-based.

Comment: Please give more details about what you are doing. Screenshots will also help. Your post currently is not too clear.

Comment: @harrymc I added screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Confirm you have access to authenticate

1. Based on your screen shot showing the use of ***Integrated Authentication*** and it failing, you will want to confirm the account which you are signed on as and running the ODBC connection test as has appropriate permission to connect the applicable SQL Server instance.

   [image]

   **Note:** *You may need to confirm this SQL security is in place with the database administrator(s) of the SQL Server instance.*

---

### Confirm you are using the correct port

2. You may need to manually specify the port which the ODBC connection will connect to the SQL Server instance in case it cannot find it dynamically or it's using the wrong port.

   Click on **Client Configuration** from the **Create a New Data Source to SQL Server** window.

   [image]

   From the **Add Network Library Configuration** window, make sure the **Dynamically determine port** is unchecked and specify the port number in the **Port number** field.

   [image]

   > **Find Listening TCP Port for the SQL Server Instance**
   >
   > ```
   > USE [master]
   > EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on', 'any', NULL, NULL, N'asc'
   > --EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'
   > ```

   **Note:** *You may need to get this information from the database administrator(s) of the SQL Server instance.*

---

### Consider using an SQL Login to authenticate

3. Consider using an SQL Login credential rather than using integrated authentication to authenticate to gain access to the SQL Server instance.

   From the **Add Network Library Configuration** window check the **With SQL Server authentication using a login ID and password entered by the user** option and then put in the **Login ID** and **Password** into those field.

   [image]

   **Note:** *You may need to get with your database administrator(s) to get this setup and to get the login ID and the password to use for this level of authentication.*

---

### Further Resources

- [Troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine)
- [Solving Connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server)
- [Both x64 and x86 ODBC Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1024601/odbcad-exe-same-datasource-in-system32-and-syswow64/1265291#1265291)

Comment: First, tell me about the which driver i will use for connecting to Progress database in ODBC Administrator because I have to connect to MS SQL Server. SQL Server is on my local machine and Progress Database is on Cloud.

Comment: "DataDirect 7.1 OpenEdge Wire Protocol" is  Skyward OpenEdge ODBC drivers. right?

Comment: I downloaded DataDirect 7.1 OpenEdge Wire Protocol drivers and use it but still, connection failed. You can see my screenshots. I already using it

Comment: Progress DB is hosting on the cloud by "IS CORPS" They gave me only hostname, port, username, and password.

Comment: If I select DataDirect 7.1 OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver then it will not ask for username and password, and if i select DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol then it will ask for username and password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73762/discussion-between-zubair-sultan-and-pimp-juice-it).

Answer (score 1):

ISCORP needs to make sure that they have enabled SQL connections on the database broker and that there have enough server slots for SQL connections to come in.

An alternative is to export the data you want into a MSSQL database and report from there.  There are tools available in the data dictionary to help this and products (pro2SQL) available to do this in realtime.

I know of a few dozen skyward customers that do this with the Pro2 product.

Comment: alternative I am doing to Export to excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Just an overview:
We had success setting up the ODBC drivers for Skyward Open Edge database. Multiple DB clients were able to use this like DBeaver. Then someone set up linked servers to these databases in SQL Server. Those remote DB tables could be queried using
select * from
openquery(remote_db, 'insert query');
Views were then made based on this approach so they can be queried in user friendly syntax.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).