# Linked Server between Progress database and MS SQL Server management studio

Tags: networking, database, sql-server, sql, odbc

I wish to set up a linked server within MS SQL Server Management 2014 to access my PROGRESS DB. The Linked Server will allow us to update the tables etc and then run our queries off of SQL Server.

I am having trouble connecting to PROGRESS via SQL Server using ODBC and I was looking for advice. SQL Server is hosted on our server and Progress DB is hosted outside on cloud.

Here is what I'm doing:

First Setup an ODBC connection to the Progress database in the ODBC Administrator in the System DSN. ( In System DSN, I am selecting DataDirect 7.1 Sql server Wire protocol ). During setup, I am entering IP address on the server name. After that, I test my connection, it gives an error:

> Verify hostname and port

Right-click on Server objects and select new linked server

Linked Server: PRO_SQL

Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
Product Name: Progress DB
Data Source: Linked_test
Provider String: DSN=linked_test;DB=Data1;UID=odbc;PWD=pass1234;HOST=reporttest;PORT=23400
Location: I HAVE THIS BLANK????
Catalog: I HAVE THIS BLANK????

The two last fields I have blank, is this the problem? what should go in there??

Here are the errors I am getting:

> Verify hostname and port

I have also tried it with another STRING and I get a separate error when I try and run a querry:

DRIVER={linked_test};UID=odbc;PWD=pass1234;DatabaseName=Data1;PORTNUMBER=23400;HOSTNAME=reporttest

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Zubair -  In case you are having an issue with the ODBC the application uses seeing the appropriate x64 or x86 version of it, you might consider defining the ODBC on your server or client machine with both versions of the tools on your Windows system. See my answer here with the full detail of these steps, etc.: https://superuser.com/questions/1024601/odbcad-exe-same-datasource-in-system32-and-syswow64/1265291#1265291 . . . If you find this answer helpful in resolving this issue you explain, let me know and whether or not you want me to add as an answer. I hope this helps.... Good Luck!!

Comment: @Pimp JuiceIT So why it's giving an error of verifying hostname and port