# Can't connect to a SQL Server from Access

Tags: windows-10, connection, sql-server

Via a Connection ODBC, we are trying to connect from an Access 2016 to a SQL Server, and we found this error message:

[image]

Both computers are in the same workgroup and they can see each other. Also they can connect to internet properly. Other computer in the same workgroup can connect to the SQL server without problems. This one is unable.  Any clue to solve this issue?

Comment: Be sure you try both x64 and x86 ODBC configurations as perhaps the Access on the other machines are only x64 whereas this machine is Access x86 or vise versa. See https://superuser.com/questions/1024601/odbcad-exe-same-datasource-in-system32-and-syswow64/1265291#1265291 for detail on the path of each ODBC configuration executable files....

Comment: Something else is to check the subnet this device is connected and be sure it's not connected to another different network or wi-fi access, or gateway than the one the SQL Server allows access. I'm not sure of those factors in your environment, but if you are connecting to a local SQL Server instance, perhaps that could be the issue. If connecting to an Internet URL SQL Server, check that DNS can resolve it even if you have Internet access maybe there's an issue at the DNS level with it.